# Use of "gain employment" expression?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions, phrase-usage

Is it appropriate to use the expression "gain employment" in the context of a business school admission essay?

> I am confident that my MBA from my previous school will help me to *gain employment* in this position.

The reason for my question is that I am not sure if "gain employment" is a good enough expression for an essay to business school.

Comment: It's an essay _to_ a business school about gaining employment in a position _at_ the business school?  It would be helpful if you could clarify the situation as it's unclear.  Any research?

Answer (score 0):

> gain employment

is an understandable phrase. The question is in what context you are using it?

It sounds like it's for a job application, in which case you will want to describe how what you studied in business school **qualifies** you for the position. The mere fact you went to business school will not ensure employment. Even if you are applying to a company which has many alumni from the same school, they will usually notice this without having to mention it.

If, however, you are chatting with your friends and say

> I am confident that my MBA from my previous school will help me <s>**to**</s> gain employment in this position.

it might be appropriate.